# Rvest html_nodes span div other items

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm scrapping through this html and I want to extract the text inside the `<span data-testid="distance">`

```
<span class="class1">
<span data-testid="distance">the text i want</span>
</span>
<span class="class2">
<span class="class1"><span>the other text i'm obtaining</span>
</span>

distancia <- hoteles_verdes %>% 
  html_elements("span.class1") %>%
  html_text()
```

The question would be how to isolate the data-testid="distance" on the html elements to later retrieve the html_text.

It's my first question posting.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [CSS attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).

For example, the [attribute|="value"] selector to select `attribute` "data-testid" with `value` = "distance" (note the single and double quotes):

```
library(rvest)

hoteles_verdes %>% 
  html_nodes('[data-testid|="distance"]') %>% 
  html_text()
```

Result:

```
[1] "the text i want"
```

Data:

```
hotel_verdes <- read_html('<span class="class1">
                           <span data-testid="distance">the text i want</span>
                           </span>
                           <span class="class2">
                           <span class="class1"><span>the other text im obtaining</span>
                           </span>')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the code i finally used 
hoteles_verdes %>% 
  html_nodes('[data-testid|="distance"]') %>% 
  html_text()